# Nvidia card defaulting to some strange windows display driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

How do I force nvidia to use the normal drivers with the nvidia control panel on desktop? This issue occured when I put the GPU on a different PCIE lane.

Comment: Should have uninstalled first, which you apparently have failed to do at least once before, & now it's found an older version, presumably relating to an older card. https://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/IO_13955.html

Comment: @Tetsujin uninstalling a couple times seems to have fixed the issue strangely it defaulted again a couple times is there a way to force windows to select a certain driver?

Comment: Uninstall all the ones you don't want it to find, ideally before removing any old GPU. It's far easier to clean up at the same time than it is to try dig out old drivers that are no longer referenced to current hardware.